# Display checkbox checked or not based on mysql table value

Tags: php

I have a form that has fields that auto populate with data from mysql table. Specifically two checkbox input fields for two types of roles; `instructor` and `contact`. I initially I stored values the values in the table as either `1` or `0` to signify `true` or `false`. A person can be one or the other, neither or both. When I try to display those values through a checkbox I am not getting a result. If the value of in the table for a particular role is `1` I want to have the checkbox `checked`. I am getting no results.

DB query and display:

```
    $db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
    SELECT     a.name, 
               a.academy_id,
               p.contact_role,
               p.instructor_role
        FROM academy a
        LEFT JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
        WHERE a.academy_id = :id
    ");
    if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':id' => $id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    $result = '';
    foreach ($results as $value){   
        $result .= "<ul>";
        $result .= "<li><input id=\"person_contact\"  name=\"person_contact\" type=\"checkbox\"". $contact_role = $value2['contact_role'] == "1" ? "checked='checked'"  : "" ." />Concact</li>";
        $result .= "<li><input id=\"person_instructor\"  name=\"person_instructor\" type=\"checkbox\"". $instructor_role = $value2['instructor_role'] == "1" ? "checked='checked'"  : "" ."/>Instructor</li>";
        $result .= "</ul>";
    $s++;   
    }
```

Comment: please post the syntax error here

Comment: @BhavikShah Posted the error

Comment: @BhavikShah fixed the syntax error but still not getting results

Comment: by `no results` means you are not getting any records from database or you mean that you are getting records from database but checkboxes are not checked properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** 
What is $value2 ? you used $value in your foreach statement.

also change

```
$contact_role = $value2['contact_role'] == "checked"
```

to

```
$contact_role = $value['contact_role'] == "1"
```

and check again

Also for html messed up:

```
$result="";
$strChecked="";
foreach ($results as $value){   
        $result .= "<ul>";
        if ($value2['contact_role'] == "1")
            $strChecked = "checked='checked'";

        $result .= "<li><input id='person_contact'  name='person_contact' type='checkbox'". $strChecked ." />Concact</li>";
        $result .= "<li><input id='person_instructor'  name='person_instructor' type='checkbox'".  $strChecked ."/>Instructor</li>";
        $result .= "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Alright, working now  but the html is displaying out of place with the echo `"<li><input id=\"person_contact_".$s."\"  name=\"person_contact_".$s."\" type=\"checkbox\"". $contact_role = $value2['contact_role'] == '1' ? "checked='checked'"  : "" ." />Concact</li>";`

Comment: did you changed $value2 to $value??

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have a problem with $value2 -- shouldn't that be just $value?

Second, unless you specify a "value" attribute on a checkbox input, it will return "On" during the get/post if checked, and will not return a value if unchecked.  Try adding a value="1" to your checkbox, and then checking the value against "1".